# I want to remove last slash and junk characters after valid url if url also contains a valid slash in htaccess using rewrite rule

Tags: .htaccess, validation, mod-rewrite

for example

valid URL - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/question2

if the URL contains  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/question2/dfjhasfu$#.
then i want to remove last slash and junk characters after valid URL

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST}!-d `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f RewriteRule ^(.+?)/([a-zA-Z0-9\.\w\W\s]+)$ $1 [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: i have tried some of this rules 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST}  !-d 
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/([a-zA-Z0-9\.\w\W\s]+)$    $1 [R=301,L,NE]  


RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST}  -d 
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/([a-zA-Z0-9\.\w\W\s]+)$ $1 [R=301,L,NE]  but this rules are also removing the valid slash

Comment: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ $1 [R=302,L,NE]  this rule works only for  alphabets and numbers but if i try to append \. or \s (special characters) then it is not working fine because of same directory and file names.I want a rule which will also work for special characters.please help

Comment: Please edit code into your question, because as you can see it is unreadable in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your url guaranteed consists of just two parts, or "questions" followed by 1 part, you can use the following rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(questions/[^/]+)/ $1 [R,L]
```

You can replace "questions"  with `[^/]+` (1 or more non-slash characters) if you want. Change `[R]` to `[R=301]` after testing everything works as expected.

Comment: thanks but what if my directory name is same for example review/prewrite.php is my url and review is my directory name and if one appends junk after php  like (review/prewrite.php/sdjfhsdf.786348w3&)   then i want to redirect it to the review/prewrite.php i.e same page...can you plz provide me some generalized rule